# Cannot send variable to partial using Cocoon (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partials, cocoon-gem, locals

i'm using Rails 3, with standard rails form and Cocoon gem. I want to send a variable to a partial through the 'link_to_add_association' using the 'render_options' provided by the gem, but i cannot make it work. The view from the partial is rendering ok and coocon is working fine (can add and remove items) except for the variable. Trying to print the variable in the view says that is undefined.
This is my code:

_form.html.erb (this is a partial called from new.html.erb)

```
<%= link_to_add_association raw('Nuevo con empleado existente'), f, parte_diario_item_indirectos, :render_options => {:locals => {:foo => 'bar'}}%>
```

_parte_diario_item_indirecto_fields.html.erb

```
<%= foo %>
```

Doing something like that results in an "undefined 'foo' error".

I've also tried:

```
<%= locals[:foo] %>
```

with the same result. Using brackets/braces around 'render_options' didn't work neither.

Comment: I see no obvious error (except for the association-name, I assume you just forgot the `:` in front), this should just work. Which version of the gem are using?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Cocoon 1.2.6

Answer (score 4):

I had a very similar issue, until I realized that `render` was also being called in the `fields_for` block right above my call to `link_to_add_association`

Here is the sample Cocoon provides, with my locals added to `link_to_add_association`:

```
= simple_form_for @project do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :description
  %h3 Tasks
  #tasks
    = f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task|
      = render 'task_fields', :f => task
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add task', f, :tasks, :render_options => { :locals => { :foo => 'bar'} }
  = f.submit
```

I was not passing in the locals to the first `render` call, so the actual undefined error was from the wrong `render`, not from `link_to_add_association`

Comment: note that the the line `= render 'task_fields', :f => task` also renders the partial and you need to pass the variables to this partial as well, so it should be `= render 'task_fields', :f => task,  :foo => 'bar'`